# How can I draw this graph by tikz, latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles

I would like to draw the graph in the picture below using LaTeX (tikz). I was trying but I do not know how to make it.

[image]shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [@chsk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595860/how-can-i-draw-this-graph-by-tikz-latex/595865#595865) answer (+1), with some effort to make code a bit more concise:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt},
bend angle = 60    
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes=dot]
\node (x1) [label=135:$x_1$] at (210:4) {};
\node (x2) [label=135:$x_2$] at (210:2) {};
\node (x3) [label=180:$x_3$]            {};
%
\node (x4) [label=225:$x_4$] at (330:2)  {};
\node (x5) [label=225:$x_5$] at (330:4)  {};
%
\node (x6) [label=  0:$x_6$] at (90:2)  {};
\node (x7) [label=  0:$x_7$] at (90:4)  {};
    \end{scope}        
\draw   (x1) -- (x3) -- (x5)
        (x3) -- (x7)
        (x2) -- (x4) -- (x6) -- (x2)
        %
        (x3) to [bend left] (x1) 
        (x3) to [bend left] (x5) 
        (x3) to [bend left] (x7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly quick-and-dirty attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] (x1) at (210:4) {};
        \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] (x2) at (210:2) {};
        \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] (x3) at (0,0)   {};
        \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] (x4) at (330:2) {};
        \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] (x5) at (330:4) {};
        \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] (x6) at (90:2)  {};
        \node[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] (x7) at (90:4)  {};
        \draw (x3) -- (x1);
        \draw (x3) -- (x5);
        \draw (x3) -- (x7);
        \draw (x2) -- (x4) -- (x6) -- (x2);
        \draw (x3) edge[out=150, in=210] (x7);
        \draw (x3) edge[out= 30, in= 90] (x5);
        \draw (x3) edge[out=270, in=330] (x1);
        \node[anchor=north east]          at (x1) {$x_1$};
        \node[anchor=south east]          at (x2) {$x_2$};
        \node[anchor=east, xshift=-0.1cm] at (x3) {$x_3$};
        \node[anchor=north east]          at (x4) {$x_4$};
        \node[anchor=north west]          at (x5) {$x_5$};
        \node[anchor=south east]          at (x6) {$x_6$};
        \node[anchor=south]               at (x7) {$x_7$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This places a a number of nodes at named coordinates (`x1` to `x7`) and draws them as circles filled with black. `inner sep=1pt` is used to shrink these circles; their size is determined by their label text, which is empty here, and `inner sep` controls how much extra space there is around the label, so you need to set that to something small to get a smaller circle.

Nodes are placed using the `<angle>:<distance>` syntax for the most part, so `x2` for instance, is two cm from the origin, at an angle of 210 degrees. (This is quite a useful Ti*k*Z feature, well worth remembering.)

Edges are drawn as usual; the curved ones specify the angles at which the edges leave the source nodes (`out=...`) and enter the target nodes (`in=...`). Usually it would preferable to use `(x2) -- (x4) -- (x6) -- cycle` instead of explicitly repeating the first coordinate, BTW, but for some reason this isn't working here; don't ask me why.

Labels are placed as nodes at the previously set coordinates; `anchor=` controls which point of the new node will be placed at the specified coordinate. The node labelling x3 is also shifted a bit to keep it from clashing with the previously-drawn lines.

I hope that this'll help --- not just with your immediate problem, but also with learning a bit of Ti*k*Z!